# Setting release dates for Android

Tags: android, windows-phone, distribution

I've got an app that needs developing cross platform with sporadic updates depending on season and to go with PR, etc.

I know I can set an initial availibility date for iPhone distribution and I can do the same for updates. However I cant seem to find if I can do this with the PlayStore. I'll need to time the initial release then time updates depending on seasons and would like to do this in advance.

Anyone know if its similar? If you know if similar can be done on Windows Phone OS too that would be an extra bonus! hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You have to submit your APK a few hours before you want the App to be available in the Play Store. Play Store does not provide a "publish from date".